# Representing real part of a complex number and Fourier Transform symbol

Tags: symbols

I want to write in math mode the real part of a complex number and I used the command `\mathcal{R}(i)`. The problem is that the R it produces is not the same as the R in most books that represent the real part. One reason is that it is small and it shouldn't be as it is not meant as a letter but as a symbol. Using the `\mathcal{F}` I had the same problem representing the Fourier Transform. What command do you use and you think is best and most beuatiful for there operations?

Comment: There's no universal symbol for the three entities; some use fraktur ℜ and ℑ for the real and imaginary part of a complex number (`\Re` and `\Im` are predefined for this). I've seen several symbols for the Fourier transform: pick one an be consistent across a paper. Better yet, do `\newcommand{\FT}{\mathcal{F}}$` and use `\FT`: you'll be able to change *all* appearances by just modifying this definition.

Comment: What can I do about the size of the letter?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: When I write `\mathcal{R}(i)` for instance how can I make the R larger?

Comment: Why larger? It's the same size as uppercase letters.

Comment: In the books I have the impression that it is represented a lot bigger.

Comment: Isn't the real part of an imaginary number 0?  ;-)

Comment: I meant complex number :p

Comment: A pointer to the books you intend might be useful.

Comment: It is just an impresion of mine. The book is printed so I can't send you a link. Maybe I have that impresion exactly because the book is printed so I can copmare it with the pdf. Anyway thank you! If I find a book online I will copy the link here :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please choose what you like. If you are not able to use Lua- or XeLaTeX, let me know.

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand*{\enlarge}[1]{\mathlarger{\mathlarger #1}}

\begin{document}  
    \begin{tabular}{llll}\toprule
        Font & Normal & Bold & Big\\\midrule
        Latin Modern Math & $\Re(i)\mscrR(i) \mscrF$&$\mbffrakR(i)\mbfscrR(i)\mbfscrF$&$\enlarge{\Re}(i)\enlarge{\mscrR}(i) \enlarge{\mscrF}$\\
        XITS Math & \setmathfont{XITS Math}$\Re(i)\mscrR(i) \mscrF$&$\mbffrakR(i)\mbfscrR(i)\mbfscrF$&$\enlarge{\Re}(i)\enlarge{\mscrR}(i) \enlarge{\mscrF}$\\
        Asana Math & \setmathfont{Asana Math}$\Re(i)\mscrR(i) \mscrF$&$\mbffrakR(i)\mbfscrR(i)\mbfscrF$&$\enlarge{\Re}(i)\enlarge{\mscrR}(i) \enlarge{\mscrF}$\\
        TeX G. P. Math & \setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}$\Re(i)\mscrR(i) \mscrF$&$\mbffrakR(i)\mbfscrR(i)\mbfscrF$&$\enlarge{\Re}(i)\enlarge{\mscrR}(i) \enlarge{\mscrF}$\\\bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
\end{document}
```

[image]